# SharePoint 2013 - On clicking of Edit icon, show popup box (or) modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016

I have a grid which displays data from the SharePoint list.

On clicking of Edit icon, it should display a popup, where it allows users to edit Expiration date and notes field as per below screenshots.

Once user clicks on save, it should save the data back to SharePoint list and grid.

May I know how it can be achieved in SP2013 visual web part?

[image]

[image]